# iOS: Old Tab Bar Icons showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, icons, uitabbarcontroller

So originally I made some custom tab bar icons that looked pretty neat, and I put them in my project. I recently just realized they look disgusting. So, I got some free tab bar icons and replaced the old ones. When the app loads, I at first see the old icons, then when the app is fully loaded I see my new icons. Now I don't want any user to see this. I then took action by permanently deleting the pictures not only from Xcode, but from my hard drive, which still did not fix the problem. I went to my DerivedData folder and emptied all my cache files. No success. This is a giant project and I don't want to have to make a new app, copy paste, make all the connections, and get all the frameworks again.

Comment: What happens if you clean build?

Comment: same result. Sorry, forgot to add that in there

Comment: If the images are still showing up, then they must be present *somewhere*. Did you double-check your nibs, etc?

Comment: As far as my computer and Xcode is concerned, they're non existent. However my simulator still shows them. I even restarted the simulator. No luck.

Comment: Is there a way I can Command+F and try to find something in my *entire* project?

Comment: Cmd-Shift-F searches for files across your entire project.

Comment: @doc92606 Had a similar problem recently, check my answer. The simulator is doing some funky catching of those resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "when the app loads" you see the old icons. By any chance are you seeing this during load of the app, before it's actually usable, and as soon as the app becomes usable it's showing the new icons? I bet your `default.png` shows the old icons and you never updated it.

Comment: Turns out i had a default.png

Comment: I deleted it but it still shows the old icons when it loads, or "before it's actually usable"

Comment: @doc92606: Clean the project, delete the app from the Simulator, and re-build.